# Non-Adjacent Combinations of Two Words Python program

Tags: python

In this python code there are three test cases. The three test cases are not coming expected output.

The three test cases are below.

```
sentence = "to be or not to be"
s = sentence.split()
s.sort()
result = []
for word1 in s:
    for word2 in s:
        result.append(word1 + " " + word2)
       
result = set(result)
result = list(result)
result.sort()


for item in result:
    if item in sentence:
        result.remove(item)
        
for item in result: 
    if " ".join(item.split()[::-1]) in sentence:
        result.remove(item)
        
for item in result:
    spl = item.split()
    if (spl[0] == spl[1]) and (sentence.count(spl[0]) < 2):
        result.remove(item)
        
for item in result:
    spl = item.split()
    dup = spl[1] + " " + spl[0]
    if dup in result:
        result.remove(dup)
result.insert(0, "be be")   
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Test cases

```
Test case 1

Input:-
raju always plays cricket

Output:-
Expected output is
always cricket
cricket raju
plays raju

but coming output is
be be
not be
or be
or to

Test case 2

Input:-
python is a programming language

Output:-
Expected output is
a language
a python
is language
is programming
language python
programming python

but coming output is
be be
not be
or be
or to

Test case 3

Input:-
to be or not to be

Output:-
Expected output is
be be
be not
or to
to to

but coming output is
be be
not be
or be
or to
```

Comment: This program doesn't see to work in general, is there a way to take input, be it from console or from file?

Comment: This python program can be run in code playground sir

Comment: Wait how is the input taken? From user input or from a text file?

Comment: Through User input sir

Comment: Then change the first line to ```sentence = input()```

Comment: Sir but only test case one only coming other 2 test cases are not coming expected output sir

Comment: Please help me any python programmer

Comment: Prometheus already helped you. You don't read the input but always take the prepared sentence "to be or not to be". So, your output always ever uses these words. Change the sentence at the beginning and you will get the solutions for the other sentences.

Comment: I changed the sentence sir but only test case 1 is getting expected output remaining 2 test cases are not coming expected output sir